# Galería bootstrap filtrada por isotope, como seleccionar filtro principal

Tags: bootstrap-4, filtro, gallery, magnific-popup

tengo mi galería totalmente funcional, pero al cargarla por primera vez (o recargarla) me aparecen todas las imágenes (sin filtros), no encuentro la manera de que cargue una sección o filtro siempre antes de escoger cualquier otro filtrado.

¿Como puedo dejar un filtro especifico para que se muestre antes de elegir cualquier otro filtro por primera vez?

Les dejo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar.

```js
 

    $('.portfolio-menu ul li').click(function(){
        $('.portfolio-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        
        
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('.portfolio-item').isotope({
            filter:selector
           
        });
        return  false;
    });

    $().ready(function() {
    var popup_btn = $('.popup-btn');
    popup_btn.magnificPopup({
    type : 'image',
    gallery : {
        enabled: true,
},
image: {
  titleSrc: function(item) {
    return item.el.find('img').attr('alt');
  }
}
});
});
```

```css
   

 .portfolio-menu{
    text-align:center;

  }
  .portfolio-menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    padding:10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition:all 05s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 05s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 05s ease;
    -o-transition:all 05s ease;
    transition:all .5s ease;
  }
  
  .portfolio-item{
    /*width:100%;*/
  }
  .portfolio-item .item{
    /*width:303px;*/
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }

.imagebox img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
  }

.imagebox:hover img {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-menu mt-2 mb-4">
        <ul>
          <li class="btn btn-outline-dark" style="margin: 2px;" data-filter=".bolsa">Bolsa</li>
            <li class="btn btn-outline-dark" style="margin: 2px;" data-filter=".esp">Especialidades</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-item row">
        <div class="item bolsa col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-sm">
            <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="https://i.ibb.co/xMW2WSB/bolsa-negra-para-basura.jpg" class="popup-btn">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/xMW2WSB/bolsa-negra-para-basura.jpg"
                alt="Bolsa negra para basura">
            </a>
            <p class="text-center">Bolsa negra para basura</p>
          </div>
          </div>
<div class="item esp col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-sm">
            <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="https://i.ibb.co/hYrfXXw/bolsa-anti-corrosiva.jpg" class="popup-btn">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/hYrfXXw/bolsa-anti-corrosiva.jpg"
                alt="Bolsa anticorrosiva">
            </a>
            <p class="text-center">Bolsa anticorrosiva</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Si cargo nuevamente el index o vuelvo a cargar la pag, me siguen apareciendo todas las imágenes hasta seleccionar una sección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que no salga nada o salga solo una sección especifica.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré como quitar la galería o la categoría principal y que solo aparezca cuando se selecciona una categoría en el menú.

Solo agregue "d-none" en las clases del div de la galería y posteriormente agregue que se quitara dicha clase al dar clic en una categoría desde JS, quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
 <div class="portfolio-item row d-none">
```

en JS:

```
$('.portfolio-item').removeClass('d-none');
```

Funciona bien hasta el momento, aun no encuentro como visualizar un "Data-filter" desde el inicio.